# Difference between poststop and terminate in Akka?

Tags: java, scala, akka

In akka the poststop method is called when an actor is stopped.

Also a watch can be configured on
the supervisor so that when an actor is terminated a Terminated message is received within the supervisor.

Is there any advantage of using the postStop instead of Terminated? The only difference I can see
is that postStop is called(within actor) when an actor is stopped and Terminated is called(within supervisor) when actor is Terminated.

When an actor is stopped is'nt it also terminated ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, `postStop()` is called from `preRestart()` default implementation of the same actor (see [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.0/index.html#akka.actor.Actor)), while `Terminated` message is sent to the parent only when the actor is really stopped, not when it is just restarted. Hence in default setup `postStop()` may be called more times than `Terminated` message is sent.

But the main idea is that `post*` and `pre*` hooks are needed to cleanup the actor's own state, and `Terminated` message (the whole watch system, in fact) is intended to coordinate multiple actors behavior and state. Their purpose is different, and while you can send custom `Terminated`-like messages from `postStop()` hook, you really shouldn't.

Comment: According to http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.0/index.html#akka.actor.Actor postStop "Is called asynchronously after 'actor.stop()' is invoked. Empty default implementation." so this means postStop is called after an explicit actor.stop is called and once it's stopped it is then terminated ?

Comment: @blue-sky, yes, `postStop()` is called after actor is stopped. And "stopped" and "terminated" is the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

`postStop` is a callback inside the actor itself. You would use that to clean up state that is internal to the actor, or fire further messages based on the state.

Watching for `Terminated` allows an external actor to be notified when another actor has died. It does not rely on the terminated actor itself to do anything.